# React Nested Route with params

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a page with this route:

```
"/Transfers/e58e63d4-ed09-430a-b2e5-5350c4510648"
```

I want to use nested route in the same page like this:

```
<Transfer transferId={this.props.match.params.id} />

<Link  to={`/Transfers/${this.props.match.params.id}/TransferItems`}>Transfer Items</Link>
<Link  to={`/Transfers/${this.props.match.params.id}/NewTransferItem`}>New Transfer Item</Link>

<Switch>
    <Route
        path="/Transfers/:transferId/TransferItems"
        exact
        render={() => <TransferItems transferId={this.props.match.params.id} />}
    />
    <Route
        path="/Transfers/:transferId/NewTransferItem"
        exact
        render={() => <NewTransferItem transferId={this.props.match.params.id} />}
    />
</Switch>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove exact from your routes then ordering routes from specific to public.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Transfer` component, you'll need to include the sub-routes you have given in your question:

```
//this is inside Transfer component's render method

render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <Link  to={`/Transfers/${this.props.match.params.id}/TransferItems`}>Transfer Items</Link>
      <Link  to={`/Transfers/${this.props.match.params.id}/NewTransferItem`}>New Transfer Item</Link>

// some other code...

      <Route
          path="/Transfers/:transferId/TransferItems"
          exact
          render={<TransferItems transferId={this.props.match.params.id} />}
      />
      <Route
          path="/Transfers/:transferId/NewTransferItem"
          exact
          render={<NewTransferItem transferId={this.props.match.params.id} />}

      />
    <div>
  )
}
```

This will derictly return the components `TransferItems` and `NewTransferItem` when ever the routes apply.

Full guide for this can be acquired from this [basic-example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic).

Comment: still it can not find the route!

Comment: Please re check the code,  I have updated it -removed the wrapping arrow function from the `render` prop for `Route` components.

Answer (score 0):

You can have nested switches, whats the problem, just do it:

```
<Transfer transferId={this.props.match.params.id} />

<Link  to={`/Transfers/${this.props.match.params.id}/TransferItems`}>Transfer Items</Link>
<Link  to={`/Transfers/${this.props.match.params.id}/NewTransferItem`}>New Transfer Item</Link>

<Switch>
  <Route
    path="/Transfers/:transferId/TransferItems"
    exact
    render={({match}) => <TransferItems transferId={match.params.id} />}  // don't use this.props.match, use the match from here <<
  />
  <Route
    path="/Transfers/:transferId/NewTransferItem"
    exact
    render={({match}) => <NewTransferItem transferId={match.params.id} />}
  />
</Switch>
```

Comment: still it can not find the route!

Comment: set up a codesandbox example. I will fix your code there.

Answer (score 0):

```
in may case i use url to save base first path then other path use it

    function DashboardRestaurant(props) {
        let {url } = useRouteMatch();
       return(

       <div className="col-12">
         <div className="dashboard-nav">
                <div className="dashboard-nav-inner">

                <ul data-submenu-title="Main">
                    <li>
                        <Link to={`${url}`}>
                            <i className="sl sl-icon-settings"></i>
                            Dashboard
                        </Link>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <Link to={`${url}/sets`}>
                            <i className="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i> Sets
                        </Link>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <Link to={`${url}/steps`}>
                            <i className="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i> Steps
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>




                </div>
            </div>
            <Switch>
             <Route exact path={`${url}`}>
                <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
              </Route>

               <Route path={`${url}/sets`} component={AddRestaurantSets}/>
               <Route path={`${url}/steps`} component={AddRestaurantSteps}/>

             </Switch>
        </div>)

        
    }
```